# The extention of updateable fields in Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I wonder why only some fields of a pod can be modified。
The updateable fields are：

1. spec.containers[*].image
2. spec.initContainers[*].image
3. spec.activeDeadlineSeconds
   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN85j.png)

In my actual business, I have a need to change the schedulername of a pod.
So i change the validating codes in the file of validation.go. And i created a second scheduler named kube-scheduler-test.
[That is pod whose schedulername is kube-scheduler-test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMLuL.png)
When i created a new pod whose schedulername is kube-scheduler-test, then the kube-scheduler-test will update the schedulername of pod to default-scheduler.
And then default-scheduler will schedule this pod to specified node.

[image]

[image]

Could you explain why only some fields of a pod can be modified and whether my method of changing the schedulername acceptable or not？

Answer (score 0):

Pods are designed to be [disposable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#working-with-pods), think of them as *immutable*. When you want to change anything about a Pod, you **create a new Pod, and throw away the old Pod**.

There are many articles explaining [immutable infrastructure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-immutable-infrastructure).

Comment: But when you create a new Pod and throw away the old Pod, the Pod's ID will be changed. That will be bad for some users

Comment: Users should not depend on specific Pod ID’s

Comment: Thanks. Is my method of changing the codes of validation.go to update Pod's schedulername acceptable?